# Any profiler for BlackBerry? (like VisualVM)

Tags: blackberry, profiler

Is there any profiler for BlackBerry? Something like VisualVM in JDK.

As far as I understand now, VisualVM does not "see" any "foreign" JVMs, such as the JVM from an emulator of BlackBerry or Android.

I have seen "BlackBerry Profiler View" in the Eclipse Plugin for BlackBerry but it is empty when a simulator is running (and my application is launched on it). I can't understand what can I do there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use breakpoints to get data from the profiler in Eclipse, see for example [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Profiling-with-Eclipse-plugin/m-p/557819#M113923) for instructions. If you want to profile the entire application, just break on a breakpoint, setup the profiler, remove the breakpoint and continue. Once you've run your software for a while, re-insert the breakpoint and refresh the profiling data once the debugger stops on the breakpoint.